# can't get exclusive lock on file

Tags: svn, macos

I've been trying to use subversion on osx 10.6 together with the synology DS211+ NAS. I've followed the different tutorials and step-by-step guide. The good news is that I have it running, the bad is that I don't understand why it is running now. Maybe someone can shed a light. In addition, it could be a help to other people facing the same issue.

1) I started off doing the following ... this gave me the error: can't get exclusive lock on file '...': Operation not supported

setup the repository on the NAS: svnadmin create test in /volumes1/svn and modified password file and svnserve.conf

On the remote computer I used finder to go to the network drive: Selected diskstation, connect as, selected "svn" directory.

tried to import directory into repository:
    svn import test file::///Volumes/svn/test -m "Initial submission"

This resulted in the exclusive lock error

2) Instead of using finder I used:

Menu "Go to server" -> "Go": smb://192.168.1.9 and selected repository directory "svn"
This worked.

**The question is:**

what is the difference between using finder to go to a networked drive compared to the menu option. I used the same password/username for both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

SVN has several warnings about putting repositories on shares.  Basically it's a very bad idea, guaranteed to cause issues.  That said, there are many ways to put a repository on a remote server; however, using a windows file share, a NFS share, or a mapped disk are not included in the ways that will work.

Read the documentation on how to properly create and maintain a repository http://svnbook.red-bean.com/.  Network shares cannot provide the required POSIX file handling required to ensure your repository is always in a consistent state.

Since SVN has two different networking protocols available between the repository and you, why do you need a third networking protocol between the first networking protocol and the files?